# Import picture for chrome extension reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, rollupjs

I tried to import a simple picture for my chrome extension and I got that :

> (!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find
> module '../img/intro.png' or its corresponding type declarations.
> src/pages/popup/App.tsx: (2:18) 2 import logo from '../img/intro.png';

[image]

My App.tsx is super simple

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../img/intro.png';

const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div  style={{ 
    }}>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <img src={logo} alt="image"/>;
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I based my app on this repo : https://github.com/rossmoody/ts-extension-starter?ref=reactjsexample.com

If I use require instead the picture doesnt show (my extension is just the little black square:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In typescript , [Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules) resolves the import using only the files with extension: `.ts` `.tsx` or `.d.ts`.

a  simple trick to fix this error :

**instead of**  : `import logo from '../img/intro.png';`

**use** :  `const logo =  require("../img/intro.png") ;`

Comment: It didnt work, I dont have the red underline but the picture doesnt show

Comment: what version, of manifest are you using ? and inspect that little black square to see if it is rendering the image correctly